# while loop in assembly language

Tags: c++, assembly

There is such code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  int a = 4;
  while(a--){
    std::cout << (a + 1) << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and corresponding code of main function in assembly code produced by g++:

```
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB957:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $4, 28(%esp)    # int a = 4;
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    movl    28(%esp), %eax     # std::cout << (a + 1) << '\n';
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, (%esp)
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movl    $10, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_c
.L2:
    cmpl    $0, 28(%esp)
    setne   %al
    subl    $1, 28(%esp)    # a = a - 1
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE957:
    .size   main, .-main
```

What are used instructions setne and testb in following fragment for?

```
 .L2:
        cmpl    $0, 28(%esp)
        setne   %al
        subl    $1, 28(%esp)    # a = a - 1
        testb   %al, %al
        jne .L3
```

Couldn't it be just so to check in while loop whether a is not zero and jump?

Comment: It implements the post-decrement operator.  Test first, modify afterwards.  The final value of a is -1, not 0.  Presumably the reason that 1 needs to be added again for display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The while condition is formally the equivalent of:

```
while ( a -- != 0 )
```

(Omitting the comparison is a legal obfuscation.)

The compiler is generating code to compare `a` with `0`, save the
results in register `al`, then decrement `a`, and then test the saved
results.

Comment: An addendum: yes, the compiler could have optimized this better, but this code is probably much easier to generate.

Comment: @Tinctorius Just looking at the code, I assumed no optimization.  (With optimization, I would expect the variable `a` to disappear completely, with it's value being held in a register.  And there are definitely more clever ways of generating the code: something like `sub a, 1; jc` comes to mind.)

Answer (score 1):

Because `a--` means

```
tmpval=a;
a=a-1;
return tmpval;
```

so compiler needs to save the previous value of `a`.
In this program, the body part of while will be executed when `a = 0` (after `a--`, so it will print `1`).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long while since I did assembler, but I would assume it's some optimisation to keep the pipelines busy / optimise register use.